# How to access an AWS s3 bucket from an AKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, azure-aks

I have some pods running in an AKS cluster which are trying to access AWS s3 buckets (using azure blobs are not an option because of the current architecture). I have read about [IAM roles for Kubernetes Service Accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html) but it mentions about EKS clsuters. Is there any way out here, can we create a service account in AKS with the IAM role to access a s3 bucket in AWS (probably in a different location)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to solve w/o involving Cognito. You need to set up following:

1. AKS OIDC issuer
2. AWS OIDC provider
3. Enable workload identity in AKS with Federated Identity

So it works like this: when you create OIDC provider in AWS you put AKS cluster issuer URL there. Then you just create a role that will have trust policy like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:oidc-provider/southcentralus.oic.prod-aks.azure.com/something/something/"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "southcentralus.oic.prod-aks.azure.com/something/something/:sub": "system:serviceaccount:AKS_NAMESPACE:AKS_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So "Federated" and "StringEquals" contain AKS OIDC issuer URL.

To test this:

If your workload-identity annotation for POD works fine - mutating webhook will inject a token inside the pod (you can find the path with "env | grep azure -i")

```
AZURE_FEDERATED_TOKEN_FILE=/var/run/secrets/azure/tokens/azure-identity-token
AZURE_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AZURE_TENANT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AZURE_AUTHORITY_HOST=https://login.microsoftonline.com/
```

Then just install AWS CLI, and run assume-role-with-web-identity using the token in the file of `AZURE_FEDERATED_TOKEN_FILE`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds Workload identity with identity federation could be a fit for your scenario.

The idea would be to enable the [OIDC feature flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-configuration#oidc-issuer) on your AKS and then create a federated identity trust between an AKS Kubernetes service account and AWS.

Maybe [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-amazon-cognito-for-federated-authentication-using-azure-ad/) and [this](https://blog.identitydigest.com/azuread-federate-aws/) articles will guide you.

Comment: This works fine but the problem is to use this managed identity inside the kubernetes pods. A intermediate job is needed to achieve this.

Comment: The best way that i have found on this is to use a secret store (inside or outside the cluster) like Vault and use something like sidecar injector or CSI driver to mount the AWS access credentials. This would make the solution independent of the cloud provider trying to access s3

Comment: @RyanDotnet were you able to achieve this with workload identity? how did you get the managed identity inside the pods? any working examples or direction. Trying to solve a similar use-case

Comment: Hi @ArnabSaha 
I have come across a better solution to do this which is independent of the cloud provider. It is using Hashicorp Vault (non-enterprise) to access s3 (or any aws resources) using dynamic aws credentials. You can find the details of the implementation here. 
https://medium.com/aws-tip/deploying-vault-ha-with-integrated-storage-in-kubernetes-using-aws-dynamic-secrets-engine-with-24b36a951f6f