# how to access secret in aws secret manager from Azure AKS cluster using external-secret operator

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-iam, azure-aks

Please can any one help with this?
I have some of my secrets in aws secret manager and I want to use them in for an application running in AKS cluster. I know I can attach an IAM role and then using azure OIDC and workload identity I could be able to do this.

I have seen a question like this here which gave me some idea from the answer provided by Pedro [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75248129/how-to-access-an-aws-s3-bucket-from-an-aks-cluster/77282024#77282024)

Steps taken already:

1. enabled both oidc issuer and workload identity on the aks cluster
2. created new oidc provider on aws iam and has attached the needed role and also have configured trust identity as below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::ACC_ID:oidc-provider/northeurope.oic.prod-aks.azure.com/vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "northeurope.oic.prod-aks.azure.com/vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

3. I created a k8s service account and attached the identity like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    azure.workload.identity/client-id: ${USER_ASSIGNED_CLIENT_ID}
  name: ${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME}
  namespace: ${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAMESPACE}
```

but when I created the clusterSecretStore it's still saying no validated provider.

Is there some I am missing. Please has anyone worked on something like this?